# Make the Powershell script apply to the subfolders and make the output behave correctly

Tags: powershell, newline, subdirectory, powershell-5.0

This PowerShell script processes CSV files and their corresponding "_Inglese" files, updating translations in the CSVs based on the contents of the "_Inglese" files. It retrieves files, imports data, updates translations, and exports the updated CSV files.

However, it has two problems:

1. It does not apply to subdirectories despite having indicated -recurse and $csvFile.DirectoryName during output
2. When the file from which it takes data is in this format:

```
# (Go in a newline)
Il mio corpo è un tempio.
※Parla con Jack.
```

It correctly gives me this result:

```
"0x00000011","Il mio corpo è un tempio.
※Parla con Jack.","My Body Is a Temple.
※Speak with Jack."
```

But the next line gives the following error:

```
"0x000000AA","","Dress Like a Pirate."
"0x00000080","Vestiti come un pirata.","Obtain a complete."
```

Instead, it should be so:

```
"0x000000AA","Vestiti come un pirata.","Dress Like a Pirate."
"0x00000080","Ottieni un completo.","Obtain a complete."
```

***_Inglese.txt**

```
Row 115 | Andiamo!
Row 116 | Il mio corpo è un tempio.
Row 117 | ※Parla con Jack.
Row 118 | Vestiti come un pirata.
```

**Raw CSV:**

```
Row 115 | "0x00000010","","Let's go!"
Row 116 | "0x00000011","","My Body Is a Temple.
Row 117 | ※Speak with Jack."
Row 118 | "0x000000AA","","Dress Like a Pirate."
Row 119 | "0x00000080","","Obtain a complete."
```

Powershell code:

```
param(
    $SourceDir = $PWD,
    $OutDir = $PWD,
    $OutFileSuffix = "output" # Define the suffix for the output file.
)

# Get all primary CSV files in the source directory.
$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Recurse -Filter "*.csv"

foreach ($csvFile in $csvFiles) {
    # Construct the name for the corresponding _Inglese file.
    $column3FileName = "{0}_inglese.txt" -f $csvFile.BaseName
    $column3FilePath = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath $column3FileName
    
    # Check if the _Inglese file exists.
    if (Test-Path $column3FilePath) {
        # Import the primary CSV file and the corresponding _Inglese file.
        $primaryCsv = Import-Csv -Encoding utf8 -Path $csvFile.FullName
        $column3Data = Get-Content -Encoding utf8 $column3FilePath
        
        # Assuming the first line in the _Inglese file is a header and we skip it.
        $column3Values = $column3Data | Select-Object -Skip 1

        # Update the second column (translation) in the primary CSV with data from the _Inglese file.
        $previousTranslation = $null
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $primaryCsv.Count; $i++) {
            if ($column3Values[$i] -match "※") {
                # Found a line in _Inglese file with ※, append it to the previous translation if available.
                if ($i -gt 0 -and $previousTranslation -ne $null) {
                    $primaryCsv[$i - 1].translation += "`n$($column3Values[$i])"
                }
            } else {
                # Otherwise, update the current translation.
                $primaryCsv[$i].translation = $column3Values[$i]
                $previousTranslation = $column3Values[$i]
            }
        }

        # Construct the output file path.
        $outputFilePath = Join-Path -Path $csvFile.DirectoryName -ChildPath ("{0}{1}.csv" -f $csvFile.BaseName, $OutFileSuffix)
                    
        # Write the entire file with BOM (Byte Order Mark) in UTF-8
        $primaryCsv | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Corresponding column3 file not found for $($csvFile.Name)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Which debugger are you using to step throught the code?

Comment: test on my file directly

Answer (score 2):

For the first issue your problem is that while you're selecting all the files within the subfolders, when you construct your `$column3FilePath` path, you're not including the folder reference.

So if `$sourceDir = "C:\Test\"`, and you have a file within a subfolder :

`C:\Test\Subfolder\test_inglese.txt`

Then the resulting `$column3FilePath` will end up as :

`C:\Test\test_inglese.txt`

not

`C:\Test\Subfolder\test_inglese.txt`

which presumably doesn't exist. You need to alter that section of code from

```
# Get all primary CSV files in the source directory.
$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Recurse -Filter "*.csv"

foreach ($csvFile in $csvFiles) {
    # Construct the name for the corresponding _Inglese file.
    $column3FileName = "{0}_inglese.txt" -f $csvFile.BaseName
    $column3FilePath = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath $column3FileName
```

to

```
# Get all primary CSV files in the source directory.
$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Recurse -Filter "*.csv"

foreach ($csvFile in $csvFiles) {
    # Construct the name for the corresponding _Inglese file.
    $column3FileName = "{0}_inglese.txt" -f $csvFile.BaseName
    $column3FilePath = Join-Path -Path $csvfile.Directory -ChildPath $column3FileName
```

Where `$csv.Directory` provides the current directory you're working from, rather than the root folder you started in.

I don't have an answer for the second question unfortunately from the info provided, though it might help to see an example of the actual raw csv and _inglese.txt file content so we can see what you're working with to get those results.

Comment: Added in bold the contents of the raw file and the *_English.txt. Thanks for the first part, I will test it as soon as possible.